# Andrioid Listview Hightlight when clicking item is not working

Tags: android, xml, listview, listviewitem

I want to highlight item when it is clicked in listview android.
**Listview.xml**

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
        android:id="@+id/submenu_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

This is Item design
**ListItem_text.xml**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submenu_layout_button"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_selector"
        android:text="Soupsdfsddfsdf"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
```

**listview_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/item_click_button1"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/submenu_bg" />
</selector>
```

**Fragment.class**

```
 HListView sb_list = (HListView) view.findViewById(R.id.submenu_button);
 sb_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        view.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

after the  view.setSelected(true); this line

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Use `listview.setOnClickListener()` in your activity class  that  will work fine